# 'mysqli_fetch_array' echoes SQL entries back twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website where you can post and see other people's posts (i.e. a social network).

I'm working on the timeline and I can see my posts twice, but other peoples posts are seen once (which is what I want). I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here's my code:

index.php

```
$query = "SELECT * from `follow` WHERE `follower` = '$username'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $postBoxNum = 0;
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0) {
    while($followRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $following = $followRow['following'];
      $getFollowingPosts = "SELECT * from `posts` WHERE post_by = '$following' OR post_by='$username' ORDER BY post_order DESC";
      $followingPostsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $getFollowingPosts);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($followingPostsResult) !== 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($followingPostsResult)) {
          require('./assets/inc/showPosts.inc.php');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

(/showPosts.inc.php is used on different parts of the site, it just echoes $row['post'])

[SQL Screenshot for 'posts'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXU6I.png)

[SQL Screenshot for 'follow'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKuSC.png)

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: @chris85 I've sorted this out since I posted this :)